# jQuery find td by attr and set input to variable

Tags: jquery, input, attr

```
 <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td data-unit="spear" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="spear" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="sword" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="sword" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="axe" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="axe" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="spy" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="spy" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="light" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="light" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="heavy" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="heavy" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="ram" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="ram" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="catapult" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="catapult" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Aanvragen" class="btn call_button" data-village="21603" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I first activated every tr that fullfilled a certain condition and set the input to 0:

```
var everytr = $('#village_troup_list tbody tr:has(input[value="Aanvragen"])')
everytr.find('input[type="text"]').val(0);
```

For each of these trs, I now want to set every td with data-unit="spear", each td with data-unit="sword", etc to my variable.

```
var numberofspear = 10;
var numberofsword = 15;
```

I tried:

```
$('#village_troup_list tbody td[data-unit="spear"]').find('input[type="text"]').val(numberofspear);
```

And some other things, but they all don't work. :( Does anyone know how I could do this?

I'll explain it a bit better: I want to set the input to my variable for each td with attr `data-unit="spear" (data-unit="myunitx".)`

Comment: You need to close your tds

Comment: Copied it from the DOM and hadn't fully openened them, that's why. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#village_troup_list').find('input[value="Aanvragen"]').val(numberofspear);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcJbj/)

And Your `html` is not looking `well` you should `close` your `tds` like,

```
<table id="village_troup_list">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-unit="spear" class="tooltip">
            <input type="text" size="2" name="spear" />
        </td>
        <td data-unit="sword" class="tooltip">
            <input type="text" size="2" name="sword" />
        </td>
        <td data-unit="axe" class="tooltip"></td>
        <td data-unit="spy" class="tooltip">
            <input type="text" size="2" name="spy" />
        </td>
        <td data-unit="light" class="tooltip"></td>
        <td data-unit="heavy" class="tooltip"></td>
        <td data-unit="ram" class="tooltip"></td>
        <td data-unit="catapult" class="tooltip"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Aanvragen" class="btn call_button" data-village="9598" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcJbj/1/)

You can set `value` of `button` by using its `class name` like

```
$('#village_troup_list').find('input.call_button').val(numberofspear);
```

[Class Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcJbj/2/)

**Updated,** to set the `numberofspear` to `spear inputs` try to use `[name=selector]`,

```
$('#village_troup_list').find('input[name=spear]').val(numberofspear);
```

[Spear Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcJbj/3/)

Comment: This changes the value of the button to numberofspear, that button can't change. And yeah sorry, I copied it from the DOM and the tags weren't closed on it because I hadn't openened them all.

Comment: Lol wow I'm retarded, didn't even see the inputs had a name too. <.< Accepted your answer.